# Spring boot development with docker intellij idea build takes too long

Tags: java, spring, docker, gradle

I am trying to setup my development environment using docker for a sprint boot application.

I am using intellij idea.

Here is the dockerfile.

```
FROM gradle:7.4.2-jdk18-alpine AS build
COPY --chown=gradle:gradle ./ /home/gradle/src
WORKDIR /home/gradle/src
RUN gradle build --no-daemon --debug

FROM openjdk:19-slim

EXPOSE 5097
EXPOSE 5005

RUN mkdir /app

COPY --from=build /home/gradle/src/build/libs/*.jar /app/spring-boot-application.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Xdebug", "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005", "-jar", "/app/spring-boot-application.jar"]
```

and docker-compose.yml is:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  hmis-config-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: 'hmis-config-service:0.0.0.1'
    ports:
      - "9060:5080"
      - "8091:5005"
    volumes:
      - myapp:/home/gradle/src
    environment:
      db.url: 'jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5432/hms'
      db.username: 'postgres'
      db.password: 'pgsroot'
      GRADLE_HOME: /usr/local/gradle
      JAVA_HOME: /usr/lib/jvm/java
      M2: /usr/local/apache-maven/bin
      M2_HOME: /usr/local/apache-maven
volumes:
  myapp:
```

Every time I try to build it, it takes a long time because it downloads all gradle dependencies. Hence even a small change takes a long time.

If project is started using

`docker-compose up # without the --build flag`

it starts instantaneously but the changes made aren't in the container.

I have tried to mount the volume /home/gradle/src to keep the dependencies synced but that didn't do anything.

What can be done to improve the build time and cache the dependencies?

Comment: I think you answered your own question. You should at least have a volume for your maven dependencies or bind mount your local .m2 folder.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you need to build the app in the docker context? If you build it outside (locally), and only copy the artefacts, you can leverage build caching from the (local) `gradle` daemon, which should increase the speeds significantly.

Essentially, you are building the project from scratch on each build/invocation.

i.e, don't build inside the `Dockerfile`, only copy the already built artefacts.

*PS: If you have to build inside the docker context (for instance, if you don't have a JDK locally), you can try to figure out where `gradle` keeps its local cache and also sync/copy that over.*

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned the issue is the build takes long time because it downloads dependencies each time.

If that is the case, you can try using [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).

Basically you download the dependencies once then you just copy them each time. This also reduces the size of the image.

#### References:

- https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/
- https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-boot-docker/
- https://gist.github.com/msauza/6a906e879549e218c54868d81161afcb
- https://hashedin.com/blog/a-guide-to-optimize-build-time-in-docker/

*P.S: I have not tried this for Spring Boot applications, but they work well for applications based on Go.*